# Heroku Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) consequences?

Tags: heroku

I have a web app on heroku which all the time is using around 300% of the allowed RAM (512 MB). I see my logs full of Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded) [an entry every second]. Although in bad condition, my app still works.

Apart from degraded performance, are there any other consequences also which I should be aware of ( like heroku be charging extra for anything related to this issue, scheduled jobs might fail etc) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge Heroku will not take action even if you continue to exceed the memory requirements.  However, I don't think the availability of the full 1 GB of overage (out of the 1.5 GB that you are consuming) is guaranteed, or is guaranteed to be physical memory at all times.  Also, if you are running close to 1.5 GB, then you risk going over the hard 1.5 GB limit at which point your dyno will be terminated.

Comment: So, it means no restarts, no need to increase the dynos, etc?

Comment: As far as I know, no.  However, I wouldn't guess that running over consistently as a strategy is a good idea, performance-wise or stability-wise.  It's not built for that.

Answer (score 0):

I also get the following every time I run a specific task on my Heroku app and check `heroku logs --tail`:

```
Process running mem=626M(121.6%)
Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
```

My solution would be to check out Celery and [Heroku's documentation on this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/celery-heroku#:%7E:text=Celery%20is%20a%20framework%20for,workers%20to%20perform%20jobs%20asynchronously.).

Celery is an open source asynchronous task queue, or job queue, which makes it very easy to offload work out of the synchronous request lifecycle of a web app onto a pool of task workers to perform jobs asynchronously.